# counting the number of elements in my array in side an array

Tags: php, arrays, laravel

I have  a problem. I am trying to count the array keys in my array using an specific element inside my array in the main array

```
public function index()
{   
            $user=User::all();
            $lead=Lead::all();
            $role=Role::all();
            $lead=DB::table('lead')
                 ->select(DB::raw('lead.id','users.number','users.username', 'lead.leadid','lead.first_name', 'lead.last_name','lead.email' ,count('lead.email') ))
                 ->where ('lead.email', '>', 1)
                 ->groupBy('lead.email')
                 ->leftJoin('users', 'users.number', '=', 'lead.assign')
                 ->get();
                $user=DB::table('users')->select('users.number','users.username')->get();

                echo "<pre>";
                print_r($lead);
                die();
}
```

Here is the output when I print it out

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [id] => 63
        [number] => 3
        [username] => shankar
        [leadid] => zcrm_125720000016007771
        [first_name] => 
        [last_name] => Amoah Owusu Richmond
        [email] => ramoahhowusu50@gmail.com
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [id] => 64
        [number] => 3
        [username] => shankar
        [leadid] => zcrm_125720000016007733
        [first_name] => Deus
        [last_name] => mathew
        [email] => mathewdeus@gmail.com
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [id] => 65
        [number] => 2
        [username] => james
        [leadid] => zcrm_125720000016007737
        [first_name] => bari
        [last_name] => safi
        [email] => barisafi57@gmail.com
    )

[3] => Array
    (
        [id] => 66
        [number] => 11
        [username] => nishupandey
        [leadid] => zcrm_125720000016007741
        [first_name] => Noorahmad
        [last_name] => Noor
        [email] => noorahmad.noor81@gmail.com
    )

[4] => Array
    (
        [id] => 67
        [number] => 12
        [username] => ravi123
        [leadid] => zcrm_125720000016007747
        [first_name] => munsanje
        [last_name] => nakeempa
        [email] => mnakeempa@yahoo.com
    )

[5] => Array
    (
        [id] => 68
        [number] => 8
        [username] => veerkishor
        [leadid] => zcrm_125720000016007751
        [first_name] => Noorahmad
        [last_name] => Noor
        [email] => noorahmad.noor71@gmail.com
    )

[6] => Array
    (
        [id] => 69
        [number] => 13
        [username] => rahul
        [leadid] => zcrm_125720000016007755
        [first_name] => painad
        [last_name] => sherzad
        [email] => painda12sherzad@gmail.com
    )
)
```

I want to count the elements using the email and check how many times the element is appearing in the array. Am trying to use the array_count_values but am not quite sure how to use it. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

In your DB::raw, you need to put "count" inside quotes. Otherwise, you will just run php count (like sizeof).

```
<?php

    $lead=DB::table('lead')
    ->select(['lead.id','users.number','users.username', 'lead.leadid','lead.first_name', 'lead.last_name','lead.email'])
     ->select( DB::raw( "count('lead.email') as total") )
     ->where ('lead.email', '>', 1)
     ->groupBy('lead.email')
     ->leftJoin('users', 'users.number', '=', 'lead.assign')
     ->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

To count how many elements have the same e-mail, I guess you have to do it manually...

```
$emails = array();
foreach ($lead as $lineNumber => $line) {
    $email = $line['email'];
    if(array_key_exists("$email",$emails) {
        $emails["$email"]++;
    } else {
        $emails["$email"] = 1;
    }
}
echo "<pre>";
print_r($emails);
```

Is that what you want ?

Comment: Can you explain what is not working please ? maybe `$email` is not a string, have to add double quotes (I edit answer)

Comment: It worked but it proved to be difficult to point to an element programatically...actually needed to use tthe other answer that talks of DB:: select

Answer (score 0):

If you want to count the number of arrays with specific property inside on big array then you need to loop over all the outer array elements and check the inner array elements.

Answer (score 0):

Simply Use Count ($array) which u want to count 
hope it will work